# Perl code to change the date format from IST/UTC to YYYY-MM-DD format

Tags: perl, date

Input:

```
$str="Thu Mar 25 01:48:45 IST 2011";
```

Desired output:

```
2011-03-25
```

I want only date, not the time.

Comment: March 25th was Friday in 2011.

Answer (score 4):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Time::Piece;
my $tstamp = Time::Piece->strptime
    ("Thu Mar 25 01:48:45 2011", "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y");
print $tstamp->strftime("%Y-%m-%d\n");
```

Comment: I don't think %Z works. I get "Error parsing time" unless I remove %Z and the timezone from the string. I think it works in strftime though.

Comment: @ runrig: Indeed, you are correct.  I had tested using EST for my own timezone.  The manpages for 'strptime()' do not mention the %Z format.  I'll edit the post to drop the timezone information with thanks.

Comment: My man pages for strptime do have %Z and %z, but from the code it looks like the only TZ allowed is GMT.

Comment: @runrig: The HP-UX 11.31 strptime() manpages lack %Z whereas Linux (Centos) shows %Z as a GNU extension. Using GMT works in Apple (Snow Leopard) too.

Comment: I was trying to say that it doesn't matter what the system strptime is, the Time::Piece XS code only handles %Z = 'GMT'

Answer (score 0):

```
use Date::Manip;
$str =~ s/[[:upper:]]{3}//;  # Remove timezone
$d = ParseDate($str);
die "Invalid date\n" unless $d;
$d=~s/(....)(..)(..).*/$1-$2-$3/;
print "$d\n";
```

Comment: Date::Manip is _never_ the right answer. Look at Time::Piece or DateTime.

Comment: @davorg Can you show me what's wrong with my code or why Data::Manip is _never_ the right answer?

Comment: @choroba: I would say "almost" never. For the reasons referred to at: http://www.perl.com/pub/2003/03/13/datetime.html#item_date%3a%3amanip

Comment: The author of Date::Manip says "Is Date::Manip the one you should be using? In my opinion, the answer is no most of the time." https://metacpan.org/module/SBECK/Date-Manip-5.54/lib/Date/Manip.pod#SHOULD-I-USE-DATE::MANIP

Answer (score 0):

Heck, if you know the format of the date, you don't even need to use a Perl module to manipulate the date and time:

```
my %months = (Jan => 1, Feb => 2, Mar => 3, Apr => 4 ...);
my $st r= "Thu Mar 25 01:48:45 IST 2011";
$st =~! /\S+\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+\S+\s+\S+(\S+)/;
my $date = sprintf "%s-%02s-%02s", $3, $months{$1}, $2;
```

Okay, this is very error prone, and you probably want to do a lot of error checking. The regular expression I used could be formatted a bit stronger (checking for characters and numbers instead of just "not white space". And, you probably want to make sure the month is valid too.

Actually, you're better off using a Date/Time module to do this. I was going to recommend Time::Piece, but James_R_Ferguson beat me to it.